# .ashx problems with Gif image type

Tags: c#, .net, image, ashx

Im trying to make a ashx page that return a image depending on a id.
Im only going to support jpeg, png and gif. 
The jpeg and png workes fine, but the gif's are giving me a hard time.

My problem is when the image type is Gif (like this [one](http://friends18.com/img/disney/0236.gif)).
The image is displayed but with a green background and no animation.

What am i missing ?
Is there a better way of making it return the images ?

This is the code i got:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    QuestMediaPresenter FPresenter = new QuestMediaPresenter();
    var lMediaId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["MediaId"]);

    if (lMediaId == null)
    {
       throw new HttpException(404, "Invalid image id.");
    }
    var lStream = FPresenter.GetMedia(lMediaId);

    context.Response.ContentType = getImageContentType(lMediaId);

    Image lImage = Image.FromStream(lStream);
    //I know the System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif  is hardcode but its not 
    //relevant to this question, will make it dynamic later, if its still the way to go.
    lImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you loading the image stream into an `Image` object, and then turn around and save the `Image` to the response stream?  Why not cut out the middle man and write `lStream` to the response stream?  Just copy one stream to another.  It's reasonable to guess that `Image` is modifying the image content.

Comment: If i write the lStream to the Response like this:
context.Response.Write(lStream); i get a a error saying the image cant display because the it contains errors, is this the right way to write it to the response ? I havent dealt that much with responses as you may understand.

Comment: you have it backwards.  `lStream.Write(context.Response, 0, lStream.Length)` or something similar.  `lStream` is the one doing the writing to the response stream.  The thing is, when you load the image into an `Image` object, and then save it from there, the `Image` is saving it's *reinterpretation* of the original image.  What you end up writing to the response is not *necessarily* the same image you loaded from `FPresenter`.

Comment: Finally found a way to solve my problem, i made a StreamToByte converter and used `context.Response.BinaryWrite(lBytes);` instead, then it all worked out, thanks for the help Inuyasha you put me on the right track